# valueChangeListener not working with PrimeFaces selectOneRadio

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectoneradio

I put a `valueChangeListener` on a primefaces `selectOneRadio` to render some components on the page according to the selected choice but it doesn't work

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="Gender"
    value="#{someBean.booleanVariable}"
    required="true"
   valueChangeListener="#{personBean.triggerGender}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{personBean.triggerGender}" render="triggerGender" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="female" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="male" /> 
</p:selectOneRadio>

personBean

public class ReportPerson {

private boolean female, male = true;
    public void triggerGender(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    System.err.println("Fired");
    if (e.getNewValue().equals("female")) {
        female = true;
        male = false;
    }
 }
```

and this is the components in the JSF page that will be rendered according to the values of the booleans `female` and `male`

```
    <h:form id="triggerGender">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Does he has " styleClass="Labels"
                            rendered="#{personBean.male}" />
                        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.male}" />
                        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.male}" />

                        <h:outputLabel for="Moustache" value="Mustache ?"
                            styleClass="Labels" rendered="#{personBean.male}" />
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
                            value="#{personBean.personDescription.moustach}"
                            rendered="#{personBean.male}" />
                        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.male}" />


                        <h:outputLabel value="Beared ? " styleClass="Labels"
                            rendered="#{personBean.male}" />
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
                            value="#{personBean.personDescription.beared}"
                            rendered="#{personBean.male}" />
                        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.male}" />


                        <h:outputLabel value="Does she wear " styleClass="Labels"
                            rendered="#{personBean.female}" />
                        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.female}" />
                        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.female}" />

                        <h:outputLabel value="Describe?" styleClass="Labels"
                            rendered="#{personBean.female}" />
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
                            value="#{personBean.personDescription.hijab}"
                            rendered="#{personBean.female}" />
                        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.female}" />

                    </h:form>
```

when I change the radioButton to female the statement `Fired` is printed in the console but the above component isn't renderedw

Comment: Don't you have a typo in your code? (`<h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBeann.female}" />` should be `<h:outputLabel rendered="#{personBean.female}" />`)

Comment: no it's a mistake in copy/paste, everything is ok in my original code

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1) You only need to use the valuechange listener if you want need to know the old value and the new value. If you're only rendering components then use:

```
 <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{personBean.triggerGender}" render="triggerGender"></f:ajax>
```

2) There needs to be a component in your form with the id 'triggerGender' if you want to ajax refresh it

3) Your radio button component is bound to #{someBean.booleanVariable}, however the item values of your select items are strings. Shouldn't they be booleans for true or false?

4) Your outputlabel should be conditionally rendered based on #{someBean.booleanVariable} and should be within a component with the id 'triggerGender'

Comment: i made it like that but the component the form with id="triggerGender" still doesn't updated

Comment: Please include the proper xhtml and your managed bean code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should nested your form inside h:panelGroup and render your PanelGroup